# how to find all possible letter combinations for the given numbers in php

Tags: php, combinations

### **I need an efficient code in PHP tat generates all possible letter combinations for the given numbers.** Assign letters for the numbers as 2-> ABC 3-> DEF 4-> GHI 5-> JKL 6-> MNO 7-> PQRS 8-> TUV 9-> WXYZ I have tried the below code, But it does not give the expected output.

```
function f_($n)
    {
        if($n<2) { return 1; }
        for($x = 2;$n-1>1;$x*=$n--);
        return $x;
    }
    function array_restore($r){
        $clean = array();
        if(is_array($r)){
            foreach($r as $k){
                $clean[] = $k;
            }
        }
        return $clean;
    }

    function cmb($val, $l, $u=false){
        $len = $l;
        $str = strlen($val);
        $tot = f_($str) / f_($str-$len);

        $combo = array();
        if($l <= $str){
            for($i=0;$i<$tot*8;$i++){
                if(substr(str_shuffle($val), 0, $len) !== @$combo[$i]){
                    $combo[$i] = substr(str_shuffle($val), 0, $len);
                }
            }
        }else{
            return "length must be less than the length of your string.";
        }
        if($u == true){
            $x = array_unique($combo);
            return array_restore($x);
        }else{
            return $combo;
        }
    }

    $res   = cmb($value, 3, true);
    echo "<pre><br/>";
    print_r($res);


       Requirements:
```

iF I give input as 628 it should generate all possible combinations of characters from 'MNOABCTUV'
Output should generate
- 2 letter combination
- 3 letter combination
- 4 letter combination
- 5 letter combination
- 6 letter combination

Example: I need all combinations of 3 letter word
    [0] => UBM
    [1] => OTV
    [2] => NAU
    [3] => OMA
    [4] => BUA
    [5] => VCM
    [6] => AVT
    [7] => AOM
    [8] => NTV
    [9] => VMB
    [10] => VOA
    [11] => OAU
    [12] => VBU
    [13] => MNV
    [14] => AMO
    [15] => OVC
    [16] => CAO
    [17] => UTN
    [18] => TVN
    [19] => TVC
    [20] => BNO
    [21] => VAN
    [22] => CBV
    [23] => VTN . .. ..  So on....

Time complexity should be less and code efficient.

Comment: So...regardless of what you do, the complexity will be O(n)!.  Second, where do the numbers come from:  Are you talking about a straight-up array?

Comment: What you're doing is going to be inherantly slow.  Finding all combinations of 2 letters will take in the best case 26^2 (676) operations.  For 10 letters it will take 26^10 (141,167,095,653,376) operations.  Why you need to do this I don't know, but I seriously doubt any reason you have could possibly be worth it.

Comment: Store the values in two dimensional array. array(2 => 'ABC', 3 => 'DEF', 4 => 'GHI', 5 => 'JKL', 6 => 'MNO', 7 => 'PQRS', 8 => 'TUV', 9 => 'WXYZ');

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr = array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z');
    $newOne = array();
    $c = count($arr); //count for your lang letters..
    for($i = 0;$i<$c;$i++){
        for($j = 0;$j<$c;$j++){
            for($k = 0;$k<$c;$k++){
                $val = $arr[$i].$arr[$j].$arr[$k];
                array_push($newOne,$val);
            }
        }
    }
```

this should work.